# Why would LocalBroadcastManager not work instead of Context.registerReceiver?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, broadcast, intentservice

I had to implement a feature to this app which consists of an `Activity` and a `Service` working on the background (it implements `Service`, not `IntentService`).

I went through a few tutorials on the Internet that are supposed to work, and they all use `LocalBroadcastManager`, which by the way is the recommended by Android:

> If you don't need to send broadcasts across applications, consider
>   using this class with `LocalBroadcastManager` instead of the more
>   general facilities described below.

I literally lost a day to find out the problem why it wouldn't work for me: it only works if I use `Context.sendBroadcast()`. and `Context.registerReceiver()` instead of the `LocalBroadcastManager` methods.

Now my app is working, but I feel I am going against the best practices, and I don't know why. 
Any ideas why it could be happening?

**EDIT:**

After I wrote this question I went further on the problem. `LocalBroadcastManager` works through a Singleton, as we should call `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).method()`. I logged both instances (in the `Activity` and in the `Service`) and they have different memory addresses. 
Now I came to another question, shouldn't a `Service` have the same `Context` as the `Activity` that called it? From [this article](http://techtej.blogspot.com.es/2011/03/android-thread-constructspart-4.html) a Service runs on the Main Thread, hence I'd think the `Context` would be
the same.

Any thoughts on that? (sorry for the long post)

**Code samples:**

**MyService**

```
public class MyService extends Service {

...

// When an event is triggered, sends a broadcast

Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.MY_INTENT);
myIntent.putExtra("myMsg","msg");
sendBroadcast(myIntent);

// Previously I was trying:
// LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(myIntent);

}
```

**MyActivity**

```
public class MainActivity {

...

private BroadcastReceiver messageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
            Log.d("onReceive", "received!");
            // TODO something
        }
    };

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(messageReceiver, new IntentFilter(MY_INTENT));
    // Previously I was trying:
    // LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(messageReceiver, new IntentFilter(MY_INTENT));
}
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've never used LocalBroadcastManager, but it sounds like you have to [register your receiver on there](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html#registerReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter%29) (i.e. `lbm.registerReceiver(...)`, not `mycontext.registerReceiver(...)`). Are you doing that?

> Now I came to another question, shouldn't a Service have the same Context as the Activity that called it? From this article a Service runs on the Main Thread, hence I'd think the Context would be the same.

The Context class is not related to threads. In fact, both Service and Activity are (indirect) subclasses of Context -- so they're their own Contexts! 
<sup><sub>That's why you can use "this" as a Context.</sub></sup>

But regardless of which context you send into `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance()`, you should be getting the [exact same LBM instance](http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/support/v4/java/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.java#getInstance) out. I can't think of any reason that you wouldn't -- except if you're running the Activity and Service in different processes?

Comment: That was my ultimately question: seems like they are in different process. I started my Service from the MainActivity with startService(serviceIntent)

Comment: And you don't have any [android:process](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html#proc) attribute set on the activity or service?

Comment: Yes, the project did have android:process=":remote" for the service in the Manifest, and I didn't notice. This was the reason for the whole problem then. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Declaration:

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver;
```

Initialization:

```
receiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        //todo
    }
};
```

Registration:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("RECEIVER_FILTER"));
```

`context` can be any type of `Context`, you can use the application context.

Unregister:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).unregisterReceiver(receiver);
```

Broadcast:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("RECEIVER_FILTER");
intent.putExtra("EXTRA", someExtra);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: I did pretty much the same, but the two LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context) are getting a different reference

Comment: Hm. Then I don't know the reason. I checked the source code of `LocalBroadcastManager` and it works from the main thread (there is used a `Handler`, which is created as `new Handler(context.getApplicationContext().getMainLooper())`).

Comment: I even called lbm.getInstance() changing `this` to `getMyApplicationContext()` in both places, still gets a different reference. Weird

Comment: Its an old answer, but worked just perfectly for me on API 28. I am using location service and trying to send lat and lon from the service back the activity. But I was not registering localbroadcast correctly.

Comment: I had mistake in this part LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);

Answer (score 7):

check out if your Service and Activity are run in different process, LocalBroadcastManager can't apply in different process.(you should see it in AndroidManifest.xml file)

Comment: What is meant by different process? What is a process here?

Comment: as for the meaning of process I suggest you search it by google, then keep this in your mind: by default, an app has only one process in name of it's package name, but developer could add process in manifest, like let a service run in different process by add a tag like this:android:process="" after service name, so if you can find the keyword "process=" in manifest file and after "=" follows a differentNameWithPackageName, then you could know it's a multi-process app.

Comment: GOt it. Could you answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39343099/why-intent-sent-by-localbroadcastmanager-from-intentservice-is-not-received-by-b Please, I am struck for almost a week.